# Windows Service HTTPListener Memory Issue

Tags: windows, vb.net, memory, service, httplistener

Im a complete novice to the "best practices" etc of writing in any code.
I tend to just write it an if it works, why fix it.

Well, this way of working is landing me in some hot water. I am writing a simple windows service to server a single webpage. (This service will be incorperated in to another project which monitors the services and some folders on a group of servers.)

My problem is that whenever a request is recieved, the memory usage jumps up by a few K per request and keeps qoing up on every request.

Now ive found that by putting GC.Collect in the mix it stops at a certain number but im sure its not meant to be used this way. I was wondering if i am missing something or not doing something i should to free up memory.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class SimpleWebService : Inherits ServiceBase
    'Set the values for the different event log types.
    Public Const EVENT_ERROR As Integer = 1
    Public Const EVENT_WARNING As Integer = 2
    Public Const EVENT_INFORMATION As Integer = 4
    Public listenerThread As Thread
    Dim HTTPListner As HttpListener
    Dim blnKeepAlive As Boolean = True

    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim ServicesToRun As ServiceBase()
        ServicesToRun = New ServiceBase() {New SimpleWebService()}
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args As String())
        If Not HttpListener.IsSupported Then
            CreateEventLogEntry("Windows XP SP2, Server 2003, or higher is required to " & "use the HttpListener class.")
            Me.Stop()
        End If
        Try
            listenerThread = New Thread(AddressOf ListenForConnections)
            listenerThread.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            CreateEventLogEntry(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        blnKeepAlive = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateEventLogEntry(ByRef strEventContent As String)
        Dim sSource As String
        Dim sLog As String
        sSource = "Service1"
        sLog = "Application"
        If Not EventLog.SourceExists(sSource) Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog)
        End If
        Dim ELog As New EventLog(sLog, ".", sSource)
        ELog.WriteEntry(strEventContent)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ListenForConnections()
        HTTPListner = New HttpListener
        HTTPListner.Prefixes.Add("http://*:1986/")
        HTTPListner.Start()
        Do While blnKeepAlive
            Dim ctx As HttpListenerContext = HTTPListner.GetContext()
            Dim HandlerThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf ProcessRequest)
            HandlerThread.Start(ctx)
            HandlerThread = Nothing
        Loop
        HTTPListner.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal ctx As HttpListenerContext)
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        sb.Append("<html><body><h1>Test My Service</h1>")
        sb.Append("</body></html>")
        Dim buffer() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString)
        ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length
        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close()
        ctx.Response.Close()
        sb = Nothing
        buffer = Nothing
        ctx = Nothing
        'This line seems to keep the mem leak down
        'System.GC.Collect()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please feel free to critisise and tear the code apart but please BE KIND. I have admitted I dont tend to follow the best practice when it comes to coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you should *not* be doing this.  Remove the Collect() call and let it run for a week.  Any decent .NET book will talk about how the garbage collector works and how it does *not* immediately release memory when you set an object to Nothing.  It doesn't kick in until you've consumed somewhere between 2 and 8 megabytes.  This is not a leak, merely effective use of a plentiful resource.

You use a new thread for each individual connection, that's pretty expensive and scales *very* poorly when you get a lot of connections.  Consider using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem instead.  Threadpool threads are very cheap and their allocation and execution is well controlled by the threadpool manager.